# Calling a select stored procedure and pass the result to a IEnumerable<Class> using code first

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I am writing a asp.net application and in my database I have a stored procedure which runs a select that joins tables and populate result based on a input id parameter.
I would like to call this stored procedure in my asp.net application and store the result in a list what approach should I take?

Answer (score 0):

In aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select User Id</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Clear Data" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="137px" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="142px"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
</form>
```

then in code behind file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue!="-1")
        {
            Getdata();
        }
    }
    public void Getdata()
    {
        using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\afrid\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exProcedure", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter idParameter = new SqlParameter("@Id", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(idParameter);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                string name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                string gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();

                ListBox1.Items.Add("Name :"+name);
                ListBox1.Items.Add("Gender :"+gender);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
    }
```

create a table 
and then a stored procedure.In Store procedure paste it,

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[exProcedure]
@Id int
AS
SELECT * from exTable where Id=@Id
RETURN 0
```

I think this will help you.